# Pattern for deleting multiple entries from redux state based on property

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm using the pattern that Dan Abramov uses in his course [Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux). In this course his state looks something like this:

```
{
  byIds: {
    123: {},
    456: {}
  },
  allIds: [ 123, 456 ]
}
```

So in addition to this general idea, imagine that instead of just a single list of todos, you had multiple lists. And each todo in the state has a listId property that references the list it belongs to. When you delete a list from the store, you'd also want to delete all todos associated with that list. I understand how to do this in the byIds part of the state because each todo in byIds would have a listId property. However I am not sure what the best way to delete todos from the allIds part of the state. A simple state and reducer below:

**TODOS STATE**

```
{
  byIds: {
    123: { listId: 'abc' },
    456: { listId: 'def' }
  },
  allIds: [ 123, 456 ]
}
```

**TODOS ALLIDS REDUCER**

```
const allIds = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE_TODO:
      return state.filter(t => (t !== action.id));
    case DELETE_TODOS_FOR_LIST:
      // ========================
      // HOW DO I DO THIS?
      // ========================
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```